# Inkscape: text on path gets clipped

Tags: inkscape, text-on-path

I have an oval shape, and want to have text on its right side. I selected both shape and text and clicked Text > Put on Path. The text appeared at the bottom of the shape and I moved it to the right by going to the beginning of the text and pressing Alt+Right.

[image: Initially, it looks ok]

After ~270 degrees, when I either hit Alt+Right or try to add spaces in front of the text, the text still moves but gets clipped.

[image: Clipped -- why?]

Why is that and how can I prevent this?

When I put the text on the left of the shape, it works fine. I can copy that, flip both horizontally and vertically, and drag it to its new place. That works, but certainly feels hackish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When text is put on path, the position of text starts from a point and starts to clip when you cross this point of reference.[image: img 1]

Here when you start tracking (Alt+ right arrow) and cross that point of reference it starts to clip because the entire space you added by tracking is a part of the sentence now.
You can place your text on the right as you suggested or by flipping the text & the ellipse both horizontally & vertically once you apply text-put on path. Now apply tracking and the result is what you need.
[image: img2]